# Converting Date from properly from excel to R

Tags: r

I have some price data in a csv file and I want to make the date column a date

```
data<- read.csv("mypath//A.csv", 1)  
head(data)
class(data$Date)
data$Date<-as.Date(as.character(data$Date))
head(data)
class(reuters$Date)
```

here are the results:

```
data<- read.csv("path//A.csv", 1)  
> head(data)
       Date        O        H        L        C       V
1 10/1/2014 40.65270 40.70990 40.17359 40.18789 2481276
2 10/2/2014 40.13783 40.21649 39.53716 39.92331 1708052
3 10/3/2014 40.20934 40.76711 40.15929 40.69560 1577280
4 10/6/2014 40.80286 40.87437 40.35236 40.45247 1157370
5 10/7/2014 40.22364 40.28085 39.32979 39.32979 1515558
6 10/8/2014 39.37269 40.41672 39.18677 40.37381 2124682
> class(data$Date)
[1] "factor"
> data$Date<-as.Date(as.character(data$Date))
> head(data)
        Date        O        H        L        C       V
1 0010-01-20 40.65270 40.70990 40.17359 40.18789 2481276
2 0010-02-20 40.13783 40.21649 39.53716 39.92331 1708052
3 0010-03-20 40.20934 40.76711 40.15929 40.69560 1577280
4 0010-06-20 40.80286 40.87437 40.35236 40.45247 1157370
5 0010-07-20 40.22364 40.28085 39.32979 39.32979 1515558
6 0010-08-20 39.37269 40.41672 39.18677 40.37381 2124682
> class(data$Date)
[1] "Date"
```

You can see that after i do data$Date<-as.Date(as.character(data$Date)) the date is not correct.  Do you know how I can get the correct date format?

Thank you.

Comment: Try after specifying the `format` in `as.Date`, i.e. `as.Date('10/1/2014', format='%m/%d/%Y')`  In your file, `as.Date(as.character(data$Date), format='%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are a few ways of getting what you want I'll point out a couple of examples:

```
data$Date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(data$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

or a very good alternative using the package lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
data$Date<-mdy(data$Date)
```

Cheers

Comment: Why can't just `as.Date` with `format` option be used?

Comment: I'm not saying it can't. I personally prefer to use on of the options I've posted. But your suggestion is a valid suggestion as well. In the end all depends what one is going to do with the data later on. Lubridate is very flexible and allows you to convert and change format very easily even with limited knowledge in R.

Comment: Okay, my comment was basically due to your first option of converting to `strptime` and then `as.POSIXct`.  Otherwise, it looks good